# mysql query to find start and end date given number of days

Tags: mysql

I am trying to query the table below to give me a start date and end date based on when there were 30 days of stock for each item. (in stock aren't consecutive)

Example if I have 30 out of the last 40 days that the item is in stock then I would have the 1st date the item was in stock and the last day the item was in stock when we reached 30 days. The end date should be as close to today as possible. I know I can do this in php code but the table will get large and be hard to store in memory.

is this even possible in sql?

```
 CREATE TABLE phppos_inventory_stock_log (
  id int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  in_stock int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  date date NOT NULL,
  item_id int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  UNIQUE KEY in_stock (item_id,in_stock,date)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

mysql> select * FROM phppos_inventory_stock_log;
+----+----------+------------+---------+
| id | in_stock | date       | item_id |
+----+----------+------------+---------+
|  1 |        1 | 2018-03-10 |       2 |
|  2 |        1 | 2018-03-11 |       2 |
|  3 |        1 | 2018-03-12 |       2 |
|  4 |        1 | 2018-03-13 |       2 |
|  5 |        1 | 2018-03-10 |       1 |
|  6 |        0 | 2018-03-11 |       1 |
|  7 |        1 | 2018-03-12 |       1 |
|  8 |        1 | 2018-03-13 |       1 |
```

In the above example for having 3 days in stock item item id 2 would be start date of 2018-03-11 to 2018-03-13 and item id 1 would be 2018-03-10 to 2018-03-13

Comment: Let's pretend that we're talking about 3 out of the last 4 days. With that in mind, see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: (I removed some redundant/unhelpful info from your table definition)

Comment: I updated question with example

Comment: So if we were only interested in item_id 1 (and just 3 days), then a valid query would be `SELECT * FROM phppos_inventory_stock_log WHERE item_id = 1 AND in_stock = 1 ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 3;` ??

Comment: What I need though is the start and end date only; I don't care about the rows just the start and end date. It is sort of a sum..When it reaches 3 then we know we have found the start date (We start the newest date).

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly, you need a dates when the item was 30x in stock.

First, we need to find the latest date, when the item were in stock `max(date)`, then we choose for each of them, when we were in stock, sorted by the order of days, we limit to the range we are interested in (30 days) and select the oldest date.

```
SELECT max(`date`) AS max_date, item_id,
  (SELECT MIN(`date`)
   FROM phppos_inventory_stock_log AS chsl
   WHERE chsl.item_id = psl.item_id
     AND in_stock = 1
   ORDER BY `date` DESC
   LIMIT 30) AS min_date
FROM phppos_inventory_stock_log AS psl
WHERE in_stock = 1
GROUP BY item_id
```

NOTE: if you have a lot of data, you will kill the database. Limit the number of returned results or retrieve a list of specific `item_id`.